# How to parse hex ISO8583 message with J8583?

Tags: java, j8583

I have tried different ways but they were not useful.

```
//parsing data from config file
messageFactory = ConfigParser.createFromClasspathConfig(CONFIG_FILE_PATH);
//messageFactory.setForceStringEncoding(true);
//messageFactory.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

IsoMessage incomingMessage = messageFactory.parseMessage(data, NetworkInterfaceConfiguration.MESSAGE_HEADER_LENGTH);
```

Comment: Can you show example outputs from the ways you tried, and an example of what you would hope to receive?

Answer (score 0):

When you say hex, do you mean binary? If so, you need to set the message factory to use binary messages. This means it will expect the message type to be in the first 2 bytes, then the primary bitmap in the next 8 bytes, secondary (if any) in the next 8 bytes, etc.

By default it's not set to read/write binary messages.